# Angularjs Post Comments

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

My Factory

```
var obj = {
    posts: [
    {
        "text":"text",
        "date":null,
        "like":0,
        "comments":[
            {"comment":"Yorum 1", "like":100},
            {"comment":"Yorum 2", "like":200},
            {"comment":"Yorum 3", "like":300}
        ]
    },
    {
        "text":"text2",
        "date":null,
        "like":0,
        "comments":[
            {"comment":"Yorum 4", "like":500},
            {"comment":"Yorum 5", "like":600}
        ]
    }
        ]
};
return obj;
```

PostCommand

```
$scope.posts = PostFactory.posts;
$scope.PostCommand = function(){
    $scope.posts.comments.push({
        "comment":$scope.comment,
        "like":0
    });
};
```

How do I add comment? If the user chooses which one to add to it 
I use routers maybe $stateParams help me?

Comment: A lot depends on how you display all this data. Question is far too broad as it is now. Show more code related to view and routing

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/pMo4g9jBAn2YDnh04JHv

Comment: Demo isn't much help without actual templates

Comment: sorry my bad Jhon Mike helped me. I have another question I wrote down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do as follows:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="(key, post) in posts">
        {{post.text}}
        {{post.date}}
        <a href="#" ng-click="postLike(key)">Like {{post.like}}</a>
        <form>
            <input type="text" ng-model="newcomment[key].comment">
            <button ng-click="postCommand(key)">Add Comment</button>
        </form>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="(keyC, item) in post.comments">
              {{item.comment}} <br/>
              <a href="#" ng-click="commentLike(key, keyC)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Like {{item.like}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Function:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope){

    $scope.posts = [
      {
          "text":"text",
          "date":null,
          "like":0,
          "comments":[
              {"comment":"Yorum 1", "like":100},
              {"comment":"Yorum 2", "like":200},
              {"comment":"Yorum 3", "like":300}
          ]
      },
      {
          "text":"text2",
          "date":null,
          "like":0,
          "comments":[
              {"comment":"Yorum 4", "like":500},
              {"comment":"Yorum 5", "like":600}
          ]
      }
    ];

    $scope.postLike = function(key) {
      var like = $scope.posts[key].like;
      like = ($scope.posts[key].like == 1) ? 0 : 1 ;
      $scope.posts[key].like = like;
    };

    $scope.newcomment = {};
    $scope.postCommand = function(key){
      $scope.posts[key].comments.push($scope.newcomment[key]);
      $scope.newcomment = {};
    };

    $scope.commentLike = function(key, keyC) {
      var like = $scope.posts[key].comments[keyC].like;
      like = ($scope.posts[key].comments[keyC].like == 1) ? 0 : 1 ;
      $scope.posts[key].comments[keyC].like = like;
    };
});
```

Comment: so sorry but i have to add "like" with comment

Comment: I will try to mount an example, just a minute!

Comment: @ooz view if you like

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/c12brbArpWbP3P88w2Jh help me? Why does not work? does not see the input model i changed your code

Comment: I will see what I can @ooz

Comment: thank you my friend i will try to change part of "like" code

Comment: i asked so many questions but last question.How do I use the http.post for comments?